# Why this transaction is revert?

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to guarantee that user has enough Eth to execute `back()`.

When you set little amount of eth in `msg.value`, there are no revert.
However, if you set almost of all Eth you have, the revert is occurred.

Even if you have enough Eth `msg.value` + Gas fee, the revert is occurred.

Why?

You can try this in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org).

1. Choose Environment
2. Choose Account which has 100 Eth
3. Set Value to 90 ether.
4. Execute back and revert.

Why?

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

    contract Back is Ownable {

      using SafeMath for uint;

      modifier affordPay() {
        require(msg.sender.balance > msg.value, "You don't have enough eth!!");
        _;
      }

      function back() external affordPay() payable {
        msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of check you are performing is not only useless but it's plain wrong.

When a user issues a transaction with 90 Ethers as value, the 90 Ethers (plus gas) is immediately deducted from the account. The 90 Ethers becomes then visible in `address(this).balance`. Therefore, also, the sender's balance is also updated and can be seen with `address(msg.sender).balance` - it will have about 9.9999 Ethers (10 minus tx costs).

So you don't need to check whether `msg.value` has an "acceptable" value - it will always contain a value which the user already committed into the transaction. Only if the transaction reverts the value is returned to the sender.

Comment: > the 90 Ethers (plus gas) is immediately deducted from the account.


I understand what is wrong. I'm completely misunderstood the payable transaction works. Thanks.